# Azure ML Exception : The code snapshot was modified in blob storage, which could indicate tampering

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to create a simple job on Azure ML from the CLI. I tried on both Compute cluster and Compute instance targets. My code is on my local machine, and I am pushing it to the computing target, while trying to download my datasets from a blob storage under the form of a data asset.
I get the following error:

```
Exception: {
    "error": {
        "code": "UserError",
        "message": "The code snapshot was modified in blob storage, which could indicate tampering. If this was unintended, you can create a new snapshot for the run. To do so, edit any content in the local source directory and resubmit the run.",
        "message_parameters": {},
        "details": []
    },
    "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "component_name": "CommonRuntime"
}
```

Here is my .yaml file:

```
display_name: FLAVA_training_BLOB_download_test
code: C:/CODE/azureml-examples/CODE_azure/
command: ls
environment: azureml:flava_env:6
compute: azureml:gpu-instance1
inputs:
  trainingData:
    type: uri_file
    path: azureml:datasetti2_blob:1
identity:
  type: user_identity
```

The instance(s) seem to be comparing the hashes of the data asset folder and the uploaded folder, which are obviously different, as one holds the dataset and the other the code. Am I looking at these different concepts the wrong way ?

According to [this issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/243585/how-to-disable-azure-ml-snapshots-(for-compute-clu)) from about 2 years ago, snapshots are also responsible for large computation time overhead, so if a solution has been found since, I would gladly use it.

Comment: You have total control of what goes into the snapshot with the .amlignore file. This plays the same role as a .gitignore so you can efficiently manage what to include in the snapshot.

Comment: Did you try creating a new snapshot for the run by editing any content in the local source directory and resubmitting the run.